# Size of PD matrices with sparse inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sparse-matrices

Let $S_{n}^{++}(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of strictly positive definite (PD) matrices on $\mathbb{R}$. We say that a matrix is $k$ sparse if it has at most $k$ nonzero elements.

Can we somehow characterize the set of PD matrices with sparse inverse ?

More precisely I am looking at the "size" of the following set (for $k \geq n$):
\begin{equation}
M_k=\{\Sigma \in S_{n}^{++}(\mathbb{R}) | \Sigma^{-1} \text{ is } k \text{ sparse } \} 
\end{equation}

For example, the space $M_n$ contains all diagonal matrices with strictly positive coefficients so it is at least "as big as" $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{n}$. It also contains sparse orthogonal matrices since if $O \in O(n)$ is $k$ sparse then $O^{-1}=O^{\top}$ is also $k$ sparse. Can we do better and have a full characterization ?